# how to use sagemaker inside pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-sagemaker

I have a simple requirement, I need to run sagemaker prediction inside a spark job

am trying to run the below

```
ENDPOINT_NAME = "MY-ENDPOINT_NAME"
from sagemaker_pyspark import SageMakerModel
from sagemaker_pyspark import EndpointCreationPolicy
from sagemaker_pyspark.transformation.serializers import ProtobufRequestRowSerializer
from sagemaker_pyspark.transformation.deserializers import ProtobufResponseRowDeserializer

attachedModel = SageMakerModel(
    existingEndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
    endpointCreationPolicy=EndpointCreationPolicy.DO_NOT_CREATE,
    endpointInstanceType=None,  # Required
    endpointInitialInstanceCount=None,  # Required
    requestRowSerializer=ProtobufRequestRowSerializer(
        featuresColumnName="featureCol"
    ),  # Optional: already default value
    responseRowDeserializer= ProtobufResponseRowDeserializer(schema=ouput_schema),
)

transformedData2 = attachedModel.transform(df)
transformedData2.show()
```

I get the following error `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved by ...

```
classpath = ":".join(sagemaker_pyspark.classpath_jars())
conf = SparkConf() \
    .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```